# How can I make a variable set by an external project added with add_subdirectory available to the scope that did add_subdirectory?

Tags: cmake, cmake-language

I have two separate git projects that I build using `cmake`.

```
Project_A
    |CMakeLists_A.txt
    |foo.H
```

In the `CMakeLists_A.txt` file, I define a variable that points to `foo.H` as follows:

```
set(var_projectA ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/foo.H)
```

I add Project A as a subdirectory in Project B, which has the following structure:

```
Project B
    |CMakeLists_B.txt
    |Subdirectory_B
        |CMakeLists_subB.txt
        |test.cpp
```

In `CMakeLists_B.txt`, I have:

```
add_subdirectory(${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/extern/Project_A)
```

How can I access the variable `var_projectA` in the subdirectory of Project B (i.e., in `CMakeLists_subB.txt`)?

Comment: The variable `var_projectA` is local to the script `extern/Project_A/CMakeLists.txt`. You cannot access it from `CMakeLists_subB.txt`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Tsyvarev So there's no way to access ```var_projectA``` in Project B? Is there a workaround I can use if I wanted to achieve this?

Comment: If you are allowed to modify `extern/Project_A/CMakeLists.txt`, then instead of normal variable `var_projectA` you could define the one in PARENT_SCOPE, or the CACHE one, or use the global property.

Comment: Thanks @Tsyvarev, please see my comment below that also responds to your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Variables in CMake are directory, function, and block scoped](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-language.7.html#variables). `add_subdirectory` creates a new directory "child scope". You can set a variable in the parent scope of a given scope by using the `PARENT_SCOPE` argument of [the `set` command](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/set.html).

Note that if you want a variable to be set at a given scope *and* the parent scope, you need to call `set` twice- once to set it at that scope, and once to set it at its parent scope.

If a parent *directory scope* isn't guaranteed to exist, you can check that [`CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR.html) is not equal to the [`CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR.html), like so:

```
if(NOT ("${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}" STREQUAL "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}"))
  set(foo "hello world!" PARENT_SCOPE)
endif()
```